# Ubuntu-Software-Center: Font unreadable

Tags: gnome, software-center, 15.04

I can't read the different software titles as you can see in the screenshot under Gnome. Is it because of the template (numix)? Or anything else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is primarily the fact that you have chosen the <kbd>Global Dark Theme</kbd>. It makes no difference whether you use the GTK theme Numix or Adawaita.